# representivity vs representativity

Tags: orthography

In the context of surveys, one of the crucial question is whether the panel/sample is representative of the population of interest.

But should we talk about the panel representivity or representativity?

I found both in the wild in the market research literature, and both return many hits on google. Being a native French speaker, `representativity` is my natural choice, but I keep seeing `representivity` in documents...

Comment: Of related interest: *[Is the word “representativity” possible?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36476)* A Google search suggests *representativity* is a term from statistics whereas *representivity* is a term from political science.

Answer (score 2):

***[Representativeness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/representativeness)*** is the term more commonly used in statistics:

> - that serves as an example or type for others of the same classification.

- [statistical rapresentativeness](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=statistical%20representativeness) vs [statistical rapresentativity](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=statistical%20representativity)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=representativeness%2Crepresentativity%2Crepresentivity&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepresentativeness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepresentativity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepresentivity%3B%2Cc0): *representativeness, representativity, representivity*

[Representativity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/representativity) is a less common variant of representativeness. (ODO)

[Representivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representivity_(politics)) appears to be used mainly in policical contexts:,

> - Representivity is a measure of how well a deliberative decisionmaking process or body represents various constituency groups. It can be applied to legislatures in a representative democracy, election methods, legislative redistricting, statistical sampling, or selection of members of committees, cabinets, juries, or judicial panels.

(Wikipedia)